What is the most stable approach for communication between UEFI Runtime Driver and Windows Kernel Driver?
In my UEFI runtime driver, I want to set some flags (UINT) based on some conditions, and then I want to read these in my windows kernel mode driver.
I cannot use the gRT->SetVariable, because the VMWare VM crashes when I call it after ExitBootServices, and I need to set these flags after ExitBootServices is called. The crash happens when attributes are set to EFI_VARIABLE_BOOTSERVICE_ACCESS | EFI_VARIABLE_RUNTIME_ACCESS, but when I use EFI_VARIABLE_RUNTIME_ACCESS alone, it gives me "invalid parameter" error, because UEFI spec says runtime access variable need to also have bootservice access. Note that the problem is not with the variable, as I can set this variable with no problem during boot, before ExitBootServices is called.
Status = gRT->SetVariable(
    VariableName,               
    &MyGuid,
    EFI_VARIABLE_BOOTSERVICE_ACCESS | EFI_VARIABLE_RUNTIME_ACCESS,
    sizeof(flagValue),                           
    &flagValue                                 
  );
What are other approaches for getting some small data from my UEFI Runtime driver to my kernel mode windows driver?

EDIT:
Following is the part of the error in the vmware.log for the VM:
2024-08-28T07:55:00.837Z In(05) vcpu-0 Triple fault.
2024-08-28T07:55:00.837Z In(05) vcpu-0 MsgHint: msg.monitorEvent.tripleFault
2024-08-28T07:55:00.837Z In(05)+ vcpu-0 A fault has occurred causing a virtual CPU to enter the shutdown state. If this fault had occurred outside of a virtual machine, it would have caused the physical machine to restart. The shutdown state can be reached by incorrectly configuring the virtual machine, a bug in the guest operating system, or a problem in VMware Workstation.---------------------------------------
2024-08-28T07:55:00.838Z In(06) vcpu-0 Vigor_MessageQueue: event msg.monitorEvent.tripleFaultSuspend (seq 227577) queued
2024-08-28T07:55:00.846Z In(05) vcpu-0 MKSGrab: MKS release: start, unlocked, nesting 0
2024-08-28T07:55:04.491Z Wa(03) vcpu-0 MONITOR PANIC: vcpu-0:ASSERT vmcore/monitor/common/cpu/x86/segment.c:590 bugNr=19580
2024-08-28T07:55:04.491Z In(05) vcpu-0 Core dump with build build-23775571
2024-08-28T07:55:04.491Z Wa(03) vcpu-0 CoreDump_Elf: dumping state of the VM


Could you write the data to disk, perhaps?

@Dai I Can't read/write to disk at this point because the underlying OS is already loaded, and EFI_BOOT_SERVICES functions such as gBS->HandleProtocol (for finding EfiSimpleFileSystemProtocolGuid, etc) are not available.  But why is EFI_RUNTIME_SERVICES such as SetVariable not working? They should work after ExitBootServices during OS load?

Does the crash repro in any other EFI VMs, like Hyper-V or VirtualBox?

@Dai I haven't tried them yet, but doesn't matter because we cannot rule out ESX VMs as many companies use it, so if it doesn't work in ESX VMs it's not a possible solution unfortunately.

Can you access all memory from the kernel driver? If so you could allocate runtime memory (before ExitBootServices) and store the information there.

@MiSimon But how would I share the kernel memory address between the kernel driver and UEFI Runtime driver to begin with? If I could've shared that, then instead of that I would just share the flag content.

Allocate the memory when your driver is loaded and set a variable with runtime and boot service access that contains the address before ExitBootServices is called.

@MiSimon This feels so unsafe, and I'm not even sure if it works properly or not, because if I recall correctly address space changes after ExitBootServices is called, so even if I write the memory address in the UEFI variable pre ExitBootServices in my UEFI driver, after ExitBootServices I'm not sure how safe it is to access that from the kernel driver. isn't there a better approach?

You would allocate a physical address, if you allocate it as runtime memory the OS has to preserve it. You need to convert the pointer when the ExitBootServices event is signaled (like any other) in your runtime driver and map the physical address into your windows drivers virtual memory.

@MiSimon  Even if this works (Wouldnt physical memory that I store during boot using SetVariable, change after ExitBootServices, hence the original problem?), the problem is this would be only a 1 way communication. Isn't there a better approach? For now I have settled with hooking gRT->GetVariable, then in the hook function I would check if the guid is my own guid, then return the specified variable that way, but I am not sure how stable it is? For now it works without any problem, but was wondering if there is a better approach?

@MiSimon Isn't there a more official way? Surely there has to be UEFI Runtime drivers out there that require communication with a kernel module in the OS?

Why do you expect that? There's the runtime services described by the UEFI specification. They exist to plug specific gaps in OS/platform interactions. Most other problems are solved more conveniently through other mechanisms.

@unixsmurf So no UEFI runtime driver needs to have a callback so the underlying OS (kernel module, etc) would be able to call?
